# Having acronym processed differently if used in acronym environment

Tags: macros, acronyms

I have a number of acronyms that depend on each other and I would like a way to determine if the usage of an acronym is in the acronym environment and if so process it in a different way than if it is not.

That is, I would like something like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{report}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}        % Math packages
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}   % Enable pdflatex


\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\acy}{\protect\@acy}%
\newcommand{\@acy}[1]{%
  \ifAC@acro
    \acl*{#1}%
  \else
    \acf{#1}
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{acronym}
\acro{q}[$Q$]{\acy{rms}reactive power}
\acro{rms}{root mean square}
\end{acronym}

\section{Text}

The \ac{q} is..... \ac{rms}...


\end{document}
```

To result in this:

[image: Wanted result]

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Tarass who posted en answer which provided a solution. I have modified it a bit since it redefined `\ac` and I would like it to be optional.

Here is the solution.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}                 % English language/hyphenation
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}        % Math packages
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}               % Enable pdflatex


\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newif\ifACR
\ACRfalse

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\acy}{\protect\@acy}%
\newcommand{\@acy}[1]{%
  \ifACR
    \acl*{#1}%
  \else
    \acf{#1}
  \fi
}
\makeatother


%%% Begin document
\begin{document}

\begin{acronym}
\ACRtrue
\acro{q}[$Q$]{\acy{rms} reactive power}
\acro{rms}{root mean square}
\ACRfalse
\end{acronym}

\section{Text}

The \ac{q} is..... \ac{rms}...

\end{document}
```

Once more, @Tarass Thank you!